# How to select a particular csv file and plot the graph from the multiple csv files folder using browser button in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib, tkinter

How I can select a particular csv file from a folder which contains 'n' number of csv files and all csv files are of the same kind with 3 columns only the values are different. So, my aim is to select a single csv file by clicking the browser button and then the graph should get plotted with the selection I made.

```
Sample csv file points
z,x,y
23,0,0
23,0.05387,6.66634
23,0.11799,13.787
23,0.19989,22.9338
23,0.3072,35.0772
23,0.56904,63.648
23,0.84889,91.5284
23,1.22228,123.65
23,1.72457,156.606
23,1.95494,167.717
23,2.25261,178.844
23,2.59162,186.982
23,2.91377,190.805
23,3.23132,190.89
120,0,0
120,0.08749,5.44471
120,0.16471,9.48296
120,0.31905,16.8751
120,0.82326,37.8111
120,1.45144,56.0784
120,2.24965,72.0364
120,3.01642,82.2629
120,3.82591,89.1323
120,4.91071,94.4476
120,6.15553,97.6881
120,7.45795,99.0951
120,8.31468,98.7398
160,0,0
160,0.1142,5.59709
160,0.24587,10.7453
160,0.77917,27.9152
160,1.50412,42.5702
160,2.4017,53.905
160,3.49796,62.7076
160,4.77411,69.3479
160,6.24681,74.2705
160,7.93673,77.5658
160,9.78794,79.1005
160,10.1071,78.9901
```

I have written a code but with my code I always need to change the 'filename'

[image: image of csv files in a folder samples]

in the 'filename.csv' and then need to select from the browser according to filename. I want to make it easy without changing the filename any csv file can be selected.

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv
import os
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
#from sympy import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        self.menuBar = Menu(top)
        top["menu"] = self.menuBar
        self.subMenu = Menu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuBar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.subMenu)
        self.subMenu.add_command( label = "Read Data",command = self.readCSV)


    def readCSV(self):
        x=[]
        y=[]
        z=[]
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        df=pd.read_csv('GF30.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
        read = csv.reader(df, delimiter = ",")
        fig = plt.figure()
        data_list = []
        ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
        buttons = next(read)
        df.set_index('x', inplace=True)
        df.groupby('z')['y'].plot(legend=True,ax=ax)
        leg = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor = [1.1, 0.7], fancybox=True, shadow=True)
        leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)
        plt.show()
        print
        for btn in buttons:
            new_btn = Button(self, text="btn", command = self.btnClick)
            new_btn.pack()
            self.root.mainloop()
    def btnClick(self):
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can put the filename into the `read_csv` call: `df=pd.read_csv(self.filename, error_bad_lines=False)`.

Comment: I also don't understand the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved I defined my syntax wrong.